Wie ist folgender Satz grammatisch korrekt? "Das Kind mochte den Anblick solcher 'süßer Hunde' oder 'süßen Hunde'."
Welche Form ist korrekt? Warum ist sie korrekt? Wie ist die fachsprachliche Bezeichnung für die korrekte Form?

Das Kind mochte den Anblick solcher süßer Hunde.

oder

süßen Hunde


Obwohl die Frage etwas anders lautet, liefert die dort akzeptierte Antwort die relevanten Fakten.

Beides ist korrekt.
"Süßen" und "süßer" sind jeweils der Genitiv Plural von "süß". Der Unterschied: Das erste ist schwach dekliniert, das zweite stark dekliniert. Eine sehr gute Zusammenfassung davon, wann stark und schwach dekliniert wird, findet sich in folgender Antwort.
Nun kann nach dekliniertem "solch" im Plural sowohl die starke als auch die schwache Deklination stehen, siehe z.B. die Usage Notes im englischen Wiktionary oder die Anmerkung zur Deklination im deutschen Wiktionary. Duden gibt nur Fallbeispiele, z.B.

das Leben solch frommer Leute oder solcher frommen, auch frommer Leute.

Wiktionary auf Englisch und auf Deutsch stimmen in einem Punkt aber nicht überein: Wiktionary auf Deutsch hat die Einschränkung auf Plural nicht. Danach wäre "solcher feiner Stoff" möglich, dass Duden nicht als Alternative zu "solch feiner Stoff / solcher feine Stoff" nennt.
